# remove scene after user successfully to login

Tags: javascript, dom, three.js

hey I am using thre js for a homepage before user login, and I wrap the scene on a DIV, but when user click login and I want to hide / clear the screen, I failed to hide it because the it hided, the dashboard can't be clicked, I think the scene renderer still stick on that page, I am on SPA ( single page application )

is anyone can give me some options to make that scene three js be remove , 
I set to be null for the scene after user login and has token, but I should manually refresh page to make all page dashboard to me working :( and when log out, the three js scene on homage gone , and I should refresh manually as well

Answer (score 0):

let me start by saying i haven't used three.js but i think you can hide the div using javascript.
In order to show or hide an element, manipulate the element's [style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). In most cases, you probably just want to change the element's [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property.

```
element.style.display = 'none';           // Hide
element.style.display = 'block';          // Show
element.style.display = 'inline';         // Show
element.style.display = 'inline-block';   // Show
```

Alternatively, if you would still like the element to occupy space (like if you were to hide a table cell), you could change the element's visibility property instead:

```
element.style.visibility = 'hidden';      // Hide
element.style.visibility = 'visible';     // Show
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when I hide, that div on hide yes, but the another div show can't be clicked, and should I restart manually, it gonna be work :(

Comment: @poppop i don't understand what you mean, can you be a bit more clear? But if you mean that another div can't show, might you have named them with the same element name.